# mongodb - check if field is one of many values

Tags: mongodb

Is there an efficient way to query a document by if a field-value is equal to at least one value in an array?

for example when I have  the following documents:

```
{email:"mail1@domain.com"},
{email:"mail2@domain.com"},
.
.
.
{email:"mail1000@domain.com"}
```

and have indexed the email field, I want to get all document's ids, whose email field's value is equal to either "mail7@domain.com","mail117@domain.com" or 100 other totally unrelated email addresses. Is it possible?

I thought it would be as easy as

```
db.users.find({email:["mail7@domain.com","mail117@domain.com", ... 99 entries ..., "mail 987@domain.com"]})
```

but I was wrong.

Whats the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator to match any of the values in an array:

```js
db.users.find(
    {email : {$in : ["mail7@domain.com", "mail117@domain.com", "mail 987@domain.com"]}}
)
```

Comment: does it take advantage of indexed fields? It seems to slow down when more documents get added to the collection...

Comment: @VanCoding, yes it does take advantage of indexed fields.  you can confirm by appending a `.explain()` to the query.

Comment: Oh, the slowdown was caused by something else. It's pretty fast :) Thank you!